# Switching Theme and back will reset the previous Theme's settings?

Tags: themes, switch-theme

Everyone,

I have a Wordpress site on my hands, and I wanted to try a new Theme; I changed the active one and, unsatisfied, I selected again the previous one... and I found the website's appearance to be changed.

Is there a safe way to restore the site's appearance or are the settings lost and I need to recreate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the theme this could happen.  It's not great coding, however I have seen that happen.  Did you restore to the exact theme though or did you make changes (even a name change will cause reverting to defaults)?

**It may be as easy as once you go activate the original theme, go into it's settings page and click save.**

Some themes in their setup section will have a back up and restore option.  If you previously backed up the settings you can restore them there.

If you don't have any of the theme backed up, you can always do an actual database restoration from before the switch and this will revert the changes back to their working state.

Comment: I see. No, I don't have a database backup - I find it baffling that no warning whatsoever is given when switching theme... I am a software developer and should be able to restore it to working order, but it's needless busywork that could have been avoided, but as you said this is really bad design...

Comment: did you try just hitting save in the theme settings?

Comment: No, I will later. How do I go about it, I click on "Customize" and then save?

Comment: i don't know the theme, but if that's where you make the changes, then yes.

Comment: Right, I found a previous backup with the layout working as it should; how do I export _only_ the theme configuration?

Comment: can you tell me your theme or confirm that you use the customizer and the themes own settings section?

Comment: My theme uses the customizer; I could not find a "Settings" page for my theme. The theme is Lifestyle Pro.

Comment: from their site:  Import / Export Settings – the Theme and SEO settings are completely portable, so you can back up, restore, and transfer settings from one install to another.  So you should have that option in when you are in the customizer.

Comment: There is no such option. I installed the "Customizer Export/Import" plugin, but it has no effect on this theme.